# Need a programs that asks user to enter 2 integers, check to see if 2nd number is multiple of first number

Tags: java, if-statement, modulo

I cannot figure out why my if-else statements are not working properly. This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class multiple {
   public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int x = 4;
        int y = 3;
        int multiple = y % x;
        while (multiple != 0){
            System.out.println("Enter two integers: ");
            x = input.nextInt();
            y = input.nextInt();
            if (multiple != 0)
                System.out.println("Oops, sorry! The second integer is NOT a multiple of the first integer.");
            else
                System.out.println("Good Job! " + y + " is a multiple of " + x + "!");
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must update your multiple variable every time you change x and y. What you have now checks if 4%3 is 0, every single time.

In other words, set multiple to y%x after you update x and y.

Comment: Won't I lose my while statement then? I need it to keep repeating until the user enters 2 integers that are multiples

Answer (score 1):

You are not updating `multiple` after taking user input.Change your code like this.it should work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class multiple {
public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int x = 4;
    int y = 3;
    int multiple = y % x;
    while (multiple != 0){
System.out.println("Enter two integers: ");
    x = input.nextInt();
    y = input.nextInt();
   multiple = y % x;
        if (multiple != 0)
            System.out.println("Oops, sorry! The second integer is NOT a multiple of the first integer.");
        else
            System.out.println("Good Job! " + y + " is a multiple of " + x + "!");
    }       
}

}
```

Comment: OK that is what was meant by repeating the variable change after the "while" statement to continue the loop?

Comment: yes seems so.for each input set you need to calculate and reset variable `multiple`.

Comment: I kept reading that but wasn't repeating the correct statement of code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To add to what Prince and playitright said, I would ask to

1. check if the number entered by user does not equal zero. This is very important else you might encounter a runtime exception.
2. you are trying y%x and not x%y.

because the datatypes you selected are all int, thus x%y should also be checked.

assume,

x=3 and y=6, your solution works, but if we just reverse the values that is x=6 and y=3, the output is not correct.

Comment: If I want the second integer to be tested as a multiple of the first integer, wouldn't I keep it as "Y%X" ??

Comment: If user enters 6 & 3 the 3 is a multiple of 6 ( 6 X 0.5 ) = 3, but if you are only considering whole number, then I think only not equals of zero is required.